# vue.jsの単一コンポーネント内でのnoscriptの記述方法

Tags: javascript, vue.js

.vueを使ったコンポーネントを使いたいのですが、
計測系タグの設置の関係でnoscriptタグの設置が必要なのですが、.vue内でnoscriptタグの設置は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

可能です。
普通に`<template>`タグの中に`<noscript>`タグを入れるだけです。